# Vector components in polar coordinates

Tags: vectors

I'm confused what is usually meant by components of a vector in polar coordinates.

See, for instance, example 9.1 from [this PDF](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/current/teach/module_home/px436/notes/lecture9.pdf). What is meant here by   $e_{\theta} $ and $e_{r}$? Is  $e_{\theta}$ an angle or no?

As can be seen from the following picture it must be angle to change under parallel transport:

[image]

But from the lecture it more looks like regular vector component with the length r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Polar Unit Vectors $e_{\theta}$ and $e_r$ are unit vectors like the Cartesian Unit Vectors $x$ and $y$.  The difference is that $e_{\theta}$ and $e_r$ change direction with position.

To see how this works, consider the point (1,0):  At (1,0) $e_r = x$ and $e_{\theta} = y$.

At the point (0,1): $e_r = y$ and $e_{\theta} = -x$.

You can think of the vectors by imaging a unit circle of radius 1.  $e_r$ always points to a position on the circle while $e_{\theta}$ is tangent to the circle that points in in a counter-clockwise (increasing angle) direction.

[image: Polar Vectors]

Comment: yes, this is how i used to picture it, but if its the case why would such vectors components change with parallel transport ? In radial direction for example.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with GR and Paralell Transport on curved spaces.  Can you give a concise example for what you're describing?  I followed 9.1 of the paper you linked and all that's showing is the dependence of $e_r$ and $e_{\theta}$ on position and how they change direction with respect to changes in coordinates $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: in another source its said that vector components in polar coordinates are a and alpha. a is projection of a vector on the ray passing through vector's origin and origin of the coordinate system, alpha is an angle from which vector is seen from coordinate system's origin. Thats the case of the picture in my first message. And it can be seen from it that as vector is parallel transported in radial direction, the alpha component changes.

Comment: I'm asking this because connection coefficents derived from both these components definitions are the same. First case can be seen in attached pdf, second is based on invariance of vector's length.

Comment: I'm still confused on what you're saying.  $\alpha$ is an angle, not a unit vector.  If I were to consider some vector $v$ and rotate it counter-clockwise by a very small angle $\alpha$ (denoting this rotated vector $v'$) then $\vec{v} + \alpha \vec{e_{\alpha}} = \vec{v'}$